# Foreach only outputs if id is 0

Tags: mysql, php

I'm developing a plugin. On the activation hook i do this:

```
/* Create category */
global $wpdb;
$rpdb_category = $wpdb->prefix . "rp_category";

if($wpdb->get_var("show tables like '$rpdb_category'") != $rpdb_category) {

    $create_table_query = "
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `{$wpdb->prefix}rp_category` (
            `cid` BIGINT ( 20 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
            `cat` VARCHAR ( 110 ) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL ,
            `catd` CHAR ( 1 ) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL ,
            PRIMARY KEY ( `cid` )
            ) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
        ";

    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
    dbDelta( $create_table_query );

    /* Insert values to category */
    global $post;
    $data = array(
        'cat' => 'Uncategorized',
        'catd' => '1',
    );
    $format = array(
        '%s'
    );

    $success = $wpdb->insert($rpdb_category, $data, $format);

}
```

I display from rp_category like this:

```
global $wpdb;
$rpdb = $wpdb->prefix . 'rp_category';

$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT LEFT(cat, 1) as letter FROM $rpdb ORDER BY cat ASC";
$results = $wpdb->get_results($sql) or die(mysql_error());
foreach( $results as $result ) { ... }
```

The issue I have is when I display from rp_category nothing is outputed in the foreach. But if i change the id of "Uncategorized" or add a new entry that gets id = 0, then everything works great. So it seems that one entry in rp_category needs to have an id of 0 to make everything work ok. But MySQL starts from 1 and not 0. How can I fix this?

Kind regards
Johan

Answer (score -1):

I actually found the issue.

It was in the foreach I found the issue where I had an unnecessary sql-query that i removed.